# Color swatches versus color labels on Product Listings

Tags: multiple-products

I am seeing several eCommerce sites showing color labels (text) instead of color swatches (not thumbnails) on their product listings. I wonder why?
I know that color labels can be good for people being color blind, but for other users visually seeing available colours, isn’t that better?

A site that uses color labels:
[image]

A site that uses color swatches:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would love to follow-up on Nash's answer with some W3C official suggestions if that helps!

According to the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG 2.2) [Success Criterion 1.4.1 Use of Color](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/use-of-color.html) "Color [should not be] used as the only visual means of conveying information, indicating an action, prompting a response, or distinguishing a visual element."

This means that (as other users have responded) color by sight shouldn't be the ONLY distinguishing information conveyed for a user to make a choice, having adjective words written out as an alternative would pass this criteria. This is to account not only for users with blindness or varying color-blindness, but maybe even users with no vision impairments and are using a tiny phone screen or poorly color-calibrated display (or everything is just super orange because I'm using a nighttime-display color shift!).

That said, this isn't an argument to hide colors completely, this just means that word descriptions are way more valuable than a color blob, might as well have both!

I say this a ton to fellow designers: [learning great accessibility](https://www.w3.org/WAI/videos/standards-and-benefits/) means you're learning to make great designs regardless of how "uncool" documentation sounds. :D

Answer (score 2):

Reasons for color labels:

- Color perception is different for people
- There are a lot of colors, so it get's harder to distinguish them. Think of having a light gray, dark gray and black.

Reasons for no color labels:

- The label is not really descriptive of the color. The second website uses mostly patterns instead of solid colors, so something like "brownish-earth" would not be very informative for the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that showing images of variations instead of color swatches clearly shows the quality of an online store. But sometimes both possibilities have a functionality.

---

- There are some online stores that use the label to show not only the color but also the color variations in different models of the same product

[image]

<sub>* *Image from [Aussiebum](https://www.aussiebum.com/mens/underwear/trunk/cottonsoft-ocean-grey/3231)*</sub>

---

- In some products, the color change does not only affect the general color, but also totally changes the type of product.

[image]

<sub>* *[adidas.com](https://www.adidas.com)*</sub>

---

- When the variation amount is minimal, placing color swatches can lead to confusion or directly not perceive that such variation exist.

[image]

<sub>*[calvinklein.co.uk](https://www.calvinklein.co.uk/unisex-oversized-organic-cotton-sweatshirt-ck-one-j40j400041yaf)*</sub>

- Some online stores use the color label to select the product and then the color swatch to custom parts of the same item. It's a way of differentiating when the client is in the item selection section than when he/she is in editing or customization.

Comment: Thank you Danielillo.
My question however was about color labels (text) versus swatches (not thumbnails).
And specifically for Product listings (index pages with many products) not Product Detail Page.

On Product Listings: what would be better: Using color labels (text) or color swatches (not thumbnails)?